# Difference between the gazebo plugins "ros_control" and "gazebo_ros_control"?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-control, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any kind human is able to explain to me the difference between "ros_control" and "gazebo_ros_control" in simple words?
Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403431/difference-between-the-gazebo-plugins-%22ros_control%22-and-%22gazebo_ros_control%22?/) by [iceberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/108427/iceberg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, `ros_control` is for controlling the robots (simulated or real ones):

- https://wiki.ros.org/ros_control,

`gazebo_ros_control` is one of the packages `gazebo_ros_pkgs`:

- https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control

for adaptation of control to the simulated URDF robot using Gazebo plugins

> Simulating a robot's controllers in
> Gazebo can be accomplished using
> `ros_control` and a simple Gazebo plugin
> adapter. An overview of the
> relationship between simulation,
> hardware, controllers and
> transmissions is shown below:
>
> [image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iceberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/108427/iceberg/) on 2022-07-06**:
Thank you.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-07-06**:
If it answers your question, you can upvote & accept it so it will be marked as solved in the question queue :)